# Can I use Shimano B03S brake pads on my Tektro HD M285 Braking system?

Tags: shimano, braking, tektro

Can I use Shimano B03S brake pads on my Tektro HD M285 Braking system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, perfect fit.

You may find third-party manufacturers offer better value though, especially for resin pads.

Comment: Will I get the same level of performance with the Shimano brake pads as I used to get with tektro pads or will there be any significant change ?